# frappe-bench install errors on macOS

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I am new `frappe-bench`, `erpnext` and I'm trying to install it on my Mac, following instructions from https://github.com/frappe/bench

These are the errors I'm getting when I run the command

`bench init frappe-bench && cd frappe-bench`

```
wasifs-MacBook-Air-3:sites wasifkhalil$ bench init frappe-bench && cd frappe-bench
Already using interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
INFO:bench.app:getting app frappe
Cloning into 'frappe'...
remote: Counting objects: 2019, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1864/1864), done.
remote: Total 2019 (delta 276), reused 832 (delta 100), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2019/2019), 12.66 MiB | 1.37 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (276/276), done.
installing frappe
INFO:bench.app:installing frappe
Command "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9j/mk4mk3qj33zd0ys_6hsw9l6h0000gn/T/pip-build-smwpqq/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/9j/mk4mk3qj33zd0ys_6hsw9l6h0000gn/T/pip-InRsiA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/wasifkhalil/sites/frappe-bench/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7/mysql-python" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9j/mk4mk3qj33zd0ys_6hsw9l6h0000gn/T/pip-build-smwpqq/mysql-python/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/bench", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('bench', 'console_scripts', 'bench')()
  File "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/bench-repo/bench/cli.py", line 40, in cli
    bench_command()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/bench-repo/bench/commands/make.py", line 19, in init
    verbose=verbose, clone_from=clone_from)
  File "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/bench-repo/bench/utils.py", line 56, in init
    get_app(frappe_path, branch=frappe_branch, bench_path=path, build_asset_files=False, verbose=verbose)
  File "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/bench-repo/bench/app.py", line 73, in get_app
    install_app(app=app_name, bench_path=bench_path, verbose=verbose)
  File "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/bench-repo/bench/app.py", line 103, in install_app
    find_links=find_links))
  File "/Users/wasifkhalil/sites/bench-repo/bench/utils.py", line 127, in exec_cmd
    raise CommandFailedError(cmd)
bench.utils.CommandFailedError: frappe-bench/env/bin/pip install -q  -e frappe-bench/apps/frappe
```

I have recently installed `python` so `setuptools` must be installed and updated, but if it is issue with `setuptools` how do I check and update, if not what should I do to fix it?

Just to make it easy to understand I'm also posting a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you add the full steps you used for installation? Did you use the easy install ansible script?

Comment: i followed steps from here https://github.com/frappe/bench and stuck on Basic Usage

Create a new bench

Comment: looking at this line " failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-zS3Gci/mysql-python/\" i guess it is something related to mysql-python

Comment: Did you do manual or easy install?

Comment: i tried both manual and easy_install and i have same error with easy_install too " failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-zS3Gci/mysql-python/\n"

Comment: @RushabhMehta can be help me fix it, i have tried on 2 macbooks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in mysql and mode.js and You may resolved this issue along ago and may be you are using new version of frappe.

Still this answer may be helpful to some newpie.

**1. Install Pre-requisites**

- Python 2.7
- MariaDB 10+
- Nginx (for production)
- Nodejs
- Redis
- wkhtmltopdf with patched Qt (for pdf generation)

**2.Installation steps**

```
mkdir projectdir
cd projectdir
virtualenv .
git clone https://github.com/frappe/bench bench-repo
sudo pip install -e bench-repo
bench init frappe-bench && cd frappe-bench
bench get-app erpnext https://github.com/frappe/erpnext
bench new-site site1.local
bench --site site1.local install-app erpnext
bench start
```

For more info [look this](https://github.com/frappe/bench)